# Why doesn't the output from the variables show on the Console using c#

Tags: c#

```
/**
Write a program in C# language to perform the following operation:

b. Finding greatest of n numbers

**/
using System;
using System.Linq;


class Greatest
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {   
        //get the number of elements
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of elements");
        int n;
        n=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] array1 = new int[n];         
        //accept the elements
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter element no:",i+1);
            array1[i]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        //Greatest
        int max=array1.Max();
        Console.WriteLine("The max is ", max);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The program doesn't output the variable's value, I can't figure out why ??

The sample output is

```
 Enter the number of elements
3
Enter element no:
2
Enter element no:
3
Enter element no:
2
The max is
```

Note no output from variables.

Thanks

Comment: Because you are not telling it! See George's answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing your [format item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx), e.g.

Change...

```
Console.WriteLine("The max is ", max);
```

to...

```
Console.WriteLine("The max is {0}", max);
```

Comment: Or `Console.WriteLine("The max is " + max);`

Answer (score 4):

```
Console.WriteLine("The max is " + max);
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter element no. {0}:", i+1);
```